# Apache Superset Native Filters

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, apache-superset

I am using iframes to display graphs plot on Apache Superset on my react application, which has native filters enabled. Due to the removal of filter boxes i switched to native filters by following the guide in [Native filter guidetext](https://www.blef.fr/superset-filters-in-url/). The native filter is set in the format as follows: native_filters=(NATIVE_FILTER-:(__cache:(label:'',validateStatus:!f,value:!('')),extraFormData:(filters:!((col:,op:IN,val:!('')))),filterState:(label:'',validateStatus:!f,value:!('')),id:NATIVE_FILTER-,ownState:())). By changeing  to the value needed to be filtered i am able to filter the graph Via url. However i am unable to filter a multi-line graph by multiple values.(eg: [,] using the native filter approach

I have tried applying values as a array and as an object but the native filters do not get triggered for my superset graph

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.